# How to setup a PHP Project to Webhosting and Localhost for working online and offline in the same time

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, xampp, web-hosting

Can I set up my CodeIgniter project on Xampp and my Web-Hosting at the same time. And When we have not internet, all data will insert to local data and after insert to my Web hosting.

Is it possible? And How can i configure my Database for this?

Update:
I use MySQL as database and connect to it with PDO.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve the quality of your question. Which database do you use and which steps have you already tried to achieve the solution?

Comment: I dont somthing because i have not any idea. I use MySQL and i connect to database with PDO method.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with database replication. In case of MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html